# Calculating average from measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

This one should be quite easy, but I can't find a way to solve it...
A very simple setup: Three tables: products, sales and budgets.

Budget has four columns from source: ProductID,StartOfperiod,BudgetNumber.
Then I've added a calculated column, "Results" which calculate saleresults by product, month and year:

```
Results =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( sales[Numbers] );
    FILTER ( sales; sales[ProductID] = Budget[ProductID] );
    FILTER ( sales; MONTH ( sales[DateofSale] ) = MONTH ( Budget[StartOfperiod] ) );
    FILTER ( sales; YEAR ( sales[DateofSale] ) = YEAR ( Budget[StartOfperiod] ) )
)
```

Works fine.

Then I added a measure for percentage of sales/budget:

```
SalesPercentage =
DIVIDE ( SUM ( Budget[Results] ); SUM ( Budget[BudgetNumber] ); 0 )
```

This also shows up fine.
I calculate for four products only, so when put in a matrix this gives a nice table showing sales results for these products.

But then I want to calculate the arithmetic average of SalesPercentage and put that value on i.e. a card. But how can I do that? All the necessary data are available in the budget table, but I can't find a way to just calculate the average of the SalesPercentage column, which is a measure. Anyone who knows how to?

Regards,
John Martin

Comment: You can't put further aggregations on a measure...You can look into using CALCULATETABLE and SUMMARIZE functions for this...If you need further assistance, we would need sample data

Comment: What are you averaging over?